# How to securely POST php variables with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a product page that I am trying to implement a rating system on.

Each product page will have the information:

productID - The ID of the product

User - The username of the user logged in

I have the following HTML for the star rating:

```
<fieldset id='ratingStars' class="rating">
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
   <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Incredibly Powerful - 5 stars"></label>
    ...
   <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
   <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Unusable - 1 star"></label>
 </fieldset>
```

I have a javascript file that is called when one of the stars is clicked, it calls a PHP file that will connect to the database and add the rating to the product:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ratingStars .stars").click(function () {
        $.post('../resources/add_rating_to_product.php',{rate:$(this).val()},function(){
        });
    });
});
```

The PHP file just connects to the database and inserts the rating into a rating table. It expects to be POSTed the data for the username, productid, and rating.

Maybe this is a stupid question, but how do I POST that data from the javascript file? I understand how to get the rating because of the object being clicked but how do I send the other 2 if they aren't in the scope of the php file. And how do I do this securely?

It's very possible that I'm going about this all wrong so any help is appreciated!

Comment: You'd need to do it via. a `post` request by using `AJAX` or some other `$http` service

Comment: @Valkyrie My question is how?

Comment: Use a hidden input in your form for the product ID. Look into submitting forms using Ajax.

Comment: Save them in an object -> then just send them in a `JSON` object.

Comment: Also the user ID should not be submitted in the form. It should be stored in a session variable.

Comment: @rybo111 The username is not submitted in the form, I am using usercake and getting it through that.

Comment: `POSTed the data for the username` suggests you are asking how to include this in the form. The form should not contain the username. So simply use a hidden input for the product ID.

Comment: @rybo111 Can I ask why I can't use a hidden input for the username?

Comment: Because anyone can edit your inputs (including hidden ones), and therefore pretend to be someone they're not. The user ID should be acquired from the session variable (presumably this is how usercake stores it).

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your form and use the onSubmit event handler. Haven't tested code.

Given the following form:

```
<form id="ratingsForm" action="../resources/add_rating_to_product.php" method="POST">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $productId; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

You can use an event handler to serialize the form data and post it using AJAX.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#ratingsForm").on("submit", function(){
    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr( 'action' ),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    } );
  });
} );
```